# Is there any libtorrent for C#?

Tags: c#, bittorrent

Is there any bittorrent protocol implementation for C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [torrentnet](http://code.google.com/p/torrentnet/) and [monotorrent](http://projects.qnetp.net/projects/show/monotorrent).

Comment: Especially monotorrent is really great imo. Don't fall into the "It has mono in its name, so it's probably not for Windows" trap though - a common problem that Mono.Addins et all had.

Answer (score 2):

Google [is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+bittorrent) in this case.

Try [Bitsharp](http://www.dzone.com/links/rss/bitsharp_c_library_for_bittorrent.html).